# Tablet Computer compatibility

Tags: discussion, mobile, compatibility

It'd be nice if the SE sites were more tablet computer accessible.

- easier use with large and imprecise pointing devices - I have some difficulty e.g. selecting one of my favourite tags instead of deleting them...
- don't rely as heavily on mouse over effects, such as with tag information and the username popup
- allow modeators to undo more of their actions more easily, like e.g. Rejecting flags.
- some browser/platform specific changes to the site. Resizing text areas is difficult without being able to, well, select and drag...

As we're a community of technology enthusiasts, I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one sometimes using a tablet device to access SU or one of the other SE sites (even though we don't consider them computers). Many questions can be answered without requiring extensive formatting or double-checking with an IDE or man page. At least with some of these devices, users can connect actual keyboards, enhancing the typing experience significantly.

While quality might suffer slightly in light of increased difficulty and less flexibility in using these devices (e.g. Not quoting from proper sources, as it's too much work), the more we support ubiquitous use of SU, the better.

Edited to add some examples:

- editing long posts is painful, since the resize control does not work and scrolling text is painfully slow.
- vote to close as duplicate dialog relies on events that are not properly sent
- mouse over stuff like the exact date and time a post was written or edited cannot be found out since the tool tip does not appear.

Comment: The question was written on such a device and it worked surprisingly well. I have I found and vanquished all typos :)

Comment: +1 tablet support would be great... although it is not currently horrible, it could be a little more friendly.

Comment: TabletPC + Stylus FTW.

Comment: @Surfasb while I previously solved the issue of inferior software by getting different hardware when I bought my first mac, I don't think this is the solution here. There are too many proper tablet devices with corresponding restrictions out there (more than stylus tablet pcs, actually) that increased design effort makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Highly unlikely, as we consider tablets "just regular computers" due to large screen size, fast CPUs, lots of memory, storage, etc.

(also, at least on iOS you can tap to get the mouseovers to appear.)

We are working on a mobile theme for smartphones though:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96917/further-progress-on-the-stack-exchange-mobile-theme

That will be rolled out within 2 weeks.

Comment: The problem is not their javascript processing capability or what the HTML rendered is capable of handling. It's the fact that there's no mouse. *All* my suggestions have this as underlying issue.

Comment: @daniel there are ways to do everything you described, at least in iOS. Zoom in to get more detail on small areas, tap to see mouseover stuff.

Comment: It seems mobile safari fails to send changed events when pasting text, making e.g. Te vote to close as duplicate dialog difficult to use. Also, mouse over for e.g. Check marks for when a question was accepted, or when a.bounty was awarded cannot be seen afaik.